# How to print from response object

Tags: python, json, dictionary, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm currently trying to get data with python from the Internet. Fortunately the Website I want to Approach Hands me the data in json Format.

Now this is my Code:

```
from GetWebJson import simple_get
import json

raw_data = simple_get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Hamburg,de')
raw_data.encoding
data_json = raw_data.json
print(data_json["temp"])
```

The simple_get function executes "Get" from the requests library and Returns the Response object.
After formatting the raw data to json In want to print the value of the key "temp". But when i debug this Code I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nikhi\source\repos\WebScraper\WebScraper\WebScraper.py", line 7, in 
    print(data_json["temp"])
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Can't I use the variable data_json like a dict? If not, how do I convert the json, which contains lists and dicts to a printable Format?

Comment: The error says that `raw_data.json` is a method, so you presumably need to call it to get the data.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this was a pretty dumb mistake which i was trying to resolve the last three hours... : I forgot the brackets to call raw_data.json().